# Unity2D C# - Player Jumping never works regardless of what i try

Tags: unity-game-engine

working on a small platformer for my university assignment, and so far its going well enough, only problem right now is that i can never get jumping to work. Either the player physically cant jump, or can jump as much as he likes even midair.

All i want him to do is jump when touching the ground, but not when in air. And as easy as that would seem... IT REFUSES TO WORK.

i use code i find online, nope. i use 2022 tutorials on player jumping scripts, nope. no matter what, he refuses to do this simple task and im so close to pulling my hair out *sobs*

I posted my code on the unity forum and all i got was "thats messy". no actual solution to the problem. Has anyone got some basic jumping code i can learn from? everything i can find is just outdated or broken...

This is the original code:

> 

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
 
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    private float horizontal;
    private float speed = 5f;
    private float jumpingPower = 15f;
    private bool isFacingRight = true;
 
    [SerializeField] private Rigidbody2D rb;
    [SerializeField] private Transform groundCheck;
    [SerializeField] private LayerMask groundLayer;
 
    void Update()
        //determining if player is grounded for the jumping mechanic
    {
        horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
 
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && IsGrounded())
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpingPower);
        }
 
        //determining jump velocity
        if (Input.GetButtonUp("Jump") && rb.velocity.y > 0f)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, rb.velocity.y * 0.5f);
        }
 
        //Controlling the jumping mechanic
        //Adding force vertically
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpingPower, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
 
        }
 
        Flip();
    }
 
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(horizontal * speed, rb.velocity.y);
    }
 
 
    private bool IsGrounded()
    {
        return Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, 0.2f, groundLayer);
    }
 
    //Flip mechanic
    private void Flip()
    {
        if (isFacingRight && horizontal < 0f || !isFacingRight && horizontal > 0f)
        {
            isFacingRight = !isFacingRight;
            Vector3 localScale = transform.localScale;
            localScale.x *= -1f;
            transform.localScale = localScale;
        }
    }
```

Wanted him to single jump, either wouldnt jump or jumped constantly in air.

Comment: You seem to be constantly setting velocity. And in fixed update, jumping or not override any previous velocity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This piece of code making your player jump any time, when player presses space button without any ground check. Probably add ground check or just remove it, cuz you are already have jump logic above

```
if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space))
{
    rb.AddForce(Vector3.up * jumpingPower, ForceMode2D.Impulse);
}
```